# Cant Append to Undefined Even When the Element Exists

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

This strange error keeps occurring where it says that it can't append to an undefined node, even though its not null.  I looked online and some say that its trying to append before the DOM finished loading, but this triggers after everything is loaded and the error persists.

Code of content script snippet:

```
function additionalcss() {
   var timelineselect = document.querySelector('#timeline');
   if (timelineselect != null) {   //it passes this so I know its not null
     console.log(timelineselect);  //this prints fine, and is defined
     const maindiv = document.createElement('div');
     maindiv.setAttribute('id', 'div-main');
     document.timelineselect.appendChild(maindiv);  //throws error here
     ReactDOM.render(<Dropdown /> , maindiv);
   }
```

Comment: Remove `document.` from `document.timelineselect`.

Comment: `I looked online and some say that its trying to append before the DOM finished loading` - Seeing you are getting a result (not null) from `document.querySelector('#timeline')` that could not be possible.  Also, the error you should have seen is `Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined` meaning `document.timelineselect` is undefined, which is expected seeing it doesn't exist. `document.timelineselect` and a variable named `timelineselect` are 2 different things.

Comment: thanks so much guys! removing document. fixed it.